# Chatter API - How to get File Preview Status?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, contentdocument

Using a Lightning Component in a Customer Community, Im displaying a file directly after the user uploads it:

```
<img src="{!'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&amp;versionId='+ v.attachment.LatestPublishedVersionId }"  />
```

The issue is, some file previews arent immediately available, as they need to  be generated.  This is mainly an issue with non-image type files (pdf/word/excel/etc).

This doesnt throw the usual 404 error, or any error it seems.  It just show the broken link image.

Salesforce seems to have a File Preview Status for previews:

> The availability status of the preview. Values are:
>
> - Available—Preview is available.
> - InProgress—Preview is being    processed.
> - NotAvailable—Preview is unavailable.
> - NotScheduled—Generation of the preview isn’t scheduled yet.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_file_preview.htm

(similar documentation in the Chatter Rest API docs)

**Is there a fairly simple way in Apex, or directly in the Lightning Component, to get this Status?**

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just do a query in SOQL on the status if you have the latest version ID?

I believe otherwise another solution could be to use the `onerror` attribute on  tags and execute javascript to handle it:

```
<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

(Or was that what you meant by "does not throw the usual 404" ?)

Comment: Correct about the error - I have used onerror before with images, and this preview does not seem to throw an error as you may expect for a broken/missing link.  Im guessing because it is a valid location, just not available yet. /// As far as a SOQL query - Ive gone through Content Document API docs and Workbench queries,  I couldnt find the Preview Status. Maybe I overlooked it